# How to conditionally map to different properties?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following classes:

```
public Company
{
    public Person Person {get; set;}
}

public Person
{ }

public Manager : Person
{ }

public Salesperson : Person
{ }

public CompanyDto
{
    public Manager Manager {get; set;}
    public Salesperon Salesperon {get; set;}
}
```

How can I change the following mapping so that `Person` is mapped to `Manager` if `Person` is of type `Manager`?

```
cfg.CreateMap<Company, CompanyDto>()
   .ForMember(dto => dto.Manager, option => option.MapFrom(model => model.Person))
   .ForMember(dto => dto.Salesperon, option => option.MapFrom(model => model.Person))
   .ReverseMap();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following mappings:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Person, Manager>().ReverseMap();
cfg.CreateMap<Person, Salesperson>().ReverseMap();
```

And you need to put condition while creating mappings like this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Company, CompanyDto>()
  .ForMember(dto => dto.Manager, option => option.MapFrom(model => model.Person is Manager ? model.Person : null))
  .ForMember(dto => dto.Salesperon, option => option.MapFrom(model => model.Person is Salesperson ? model.Person : null));
```

For above mapping, `ReverseMap` will not work. You need to explicitely set the reverse mappings like this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<CompanyDto, Company>()
     .ForMember(dto => dto.Person, option => option.MapFrom(model => model.Manager != null ? (Person)model.Manager : model.Salesperon));
```

Hope this helps.